# Datatable reset during foreach loop

Tags: foreach, reset

I'm currently stuck on an issue that I cannot understand:

The following code produce a Datatable ("outDT") in order to populate a gridview later on. The datatable is build using rows of others datatables issued from various SQL quieres (those "get" function that return also Datatable).

The issue come when I call the "getAverage" method. Right after the call, the "pcDT" Datatable is nullified and cause a further "Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute." error on next loop.

I never modified a single row of the "pcDT" Datatable in the foreach loop, nor in the problematic "getAverage" method.

```
    public DataTable getReportTable(int idClient)
    {
        Object thisLock = new Object();

        DataTable outDT = new DataTable();
        outDT.Columns.Add("PC Name");

        DataTable pcDT = getPCNames(idClient);
        *foreach (DataRow pcRow in pcDT.Rows)*
        {
            DataRow outRow = outDT.NewRow();
            outRow["PC Name"] = pcRow["Name"];

            **DataTable collectedDT = getAverage((int)pcRow["idPC"]);**
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in collectedDT.Rows)
            {
                outDT.Columns.Add(dataRow["name"].ToString());
                outRow[dataRow["name"].ToString()] = dataRow["AVG(MeasurePoint.dataValue)"];
            }

            outDT.Rows.Add(outRow);
        }

        return outDT;
    }
```

(*)This foreach cause the famous "Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute." error

(**) And here his the method call that reset the "pcDT" Datatable. This function simply call a mySQL queries and retrieve a Datatable.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, I've found my mistake. It was in the class that manage basic SQLQueries; I used a Datatable instance that is linked to the class and not to the method, so when I recall a method that used this instance, I lost previous filled Datatable...

My bad :/